# how to put the lines 4 , 5 ,and 30, at the beginning followed by the rest of lines

Tags: sorting, awk, bash

I looking to way to put the line number 5 ,7 ,and 8 at first followed by the rest of lines :

the file i have looks like :

```
3   0.14239002E-02  0.22510807E-04 -0.26742979E-05  
4   0.57704593E-03  0.68034193E-03  0.68119554E-03  
5   0.64948134E-03  0.18797759E-04  0.92341181E-04 
6  -0.70701827E-03  0.14093323E-02 -0.88504803E-04  
7  -0.99123291E-03  0.53649558E-05  0.56815134E-03 
8  -0.10869857E-02  0.17371795E-02 -0.25683281E-03 
9  -0.16270520E-02 -0.44482889E-06 -0.97268563E-05
```

I need the output to be like:

```
5   0.64948134E-03  0.18797759E-04  0.92341181E-04  
7  -0.99123291E-03  0.53649558E-05  0.56815134E-03  
8  -0.10869857E-02  0.17371795E-02 -0.25683281E-03   
3   0.14239002E-02  0.22510807E-04 -0.26742979E-05  
4   0.57704593E-03  0.68034193E-03  0.68119554E-03  
6  -0.70701827E-03  0.14093323E-02 -0.88504803E-04  
9  -0.16270520E-02 -0.44482889E-06 -0.97268563E-05
```

Any suggest using `sort` or `awk` or some good way, thank you.

Comment: You mention `sort`, but your desired output does not appear to be sorted.

Comment: thank you , actually i don't know exactly wich way possible , i just guessed

Comment: i may suggets using maybe grep the line 5 7 8  into seperated file and put the other lines after deleting 5 7 8 lines into another file and then cat them , but maybe there would be easier method

Comment: Please [edit] your question and title to make it clear which lines you're trying to move. At the moment, you say "line number 5" but it looks like you really mean "the line starting with the number 5".

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind reading the file twice, then you can do it with awk:

```
awk '(NR == FNR && (FNR == 5 || FNR == 7 || FNR == 8)) \
  || (NR != FNR && !(FNR == 5 || FNR == 7 || FNR == 8))' file file
```

Or if you prefer, and your version of awk supports it, then you can use `xor`:

```
awk '!xor(NR == FNR, FNR == 5 || FNR == 7 || FNR == 8)' file file
```

If it's the contents of the first field `$1` that you want, not the line number `NR`, then change the comparisons `FNR == 5` to `$1 == 5`, etc.

The result of the command will go to standard output. If you want to redirect it to a file, then add a redirection to the end of the command.

Comment: thank you , i tried with this one but nothing chnges the same file i got , is it file file i have to write the same file same and i return the result into > file1

Comment: Yes, you need to redirect the output to a different file.

Comment: i did but the our pur was duplicated entries without changes

Answer (score 0):

A generic solution

```
awk -v NewOrder='5 7 8' '
   # prepare the list
   BEGIN{ 
      NOSize = split( NewOrder, NOs)
      for ( i=1; i<=NOSize; i++) Big = Big < NOs[i] ? NOs[i] : Big
      }

   # print line out of scope (of order change)
   $1 > Big { print;next}

   # load in memory line until last order change
      { Ls[$1]=$0; Rs[++j]=$1 }

   # when reaching last line to print in other order, print the new order content
   $1 == Big {
      #print new line first
      for ( k=1; k<=NOSize; k++){i=NOs[k];print Ls[i]; Ps[i]=1}
      # print the other in FIFO order
      for ( k=1; k<=(j-1); k++) {i=Rs[k];if (! Ps[i]) print Ls[i]}
      }
   ' YourFile
```

- put the list of list with pattern to change in variable NewOrder separate by a space
- take first field as reference and not number of line for line reorder

Comment: does it need something to run. since when i posted chnging my file name it  is stopping without doing any thing

Comment: normaly just adapting your filename (YourFile) and *order* list. For debuging, put some `print "here"` in sections